# Amazon Web Service - BeginCreateDBSnapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Has anyone used this?  I am having trouble finding any code examples.

```
AmazonRDS rds = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonRDSClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

CreateDBSnapshotRequest request = new CreateDBSnapshotRequest();
request.DBInstanceIdentifier = db;

object state = null;

rds.BeginCreateDBSnapshot(request, delegate(IAsyncResult ar) { }, state);
```

What I want to do is create the backup, which I can already do but I want to get notified when the backup is complete so I can proceed with my next step.